# Event Creation is not working

Tags: c#, .net

I have source "Source401" used for log "Log401". I need to use this source for "Log402" log and delete the log "Log401".  (If we can rename “Log401” as “Log402” that is also fine. But all this need to be done programmatically)

With the code below, I am getting the following exception. What is the best way to achieve it?

> Source Source401 already exists on the local computer.

Note: When I delete the old log, it is working fine. But the events are not getting created.

**UPDATE**

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7y6sy21.aspx)

> The operating system stores event logs as files. When you use EventLogInstaller or CreateEventSource to create a new event log, the associated file is stored in the %SystemRoot%\System32\Config directory on the specified computer. The file name is set by appending the first 8 characters of the Log property with the ".evt" file name extension.
>
> The source must be unique on the local computer; a new source name cannot match an existing source name or an existing event log name. Each source can write to only one event log at a time; however, your application can use multiple sources to write to multiple event logs.

**CODE**

```
  string source = "Source401";
  string logName = "Log402";
  string oldLogName = "Log401";
  string eventName = "Sample Event";
  string machineName = ".";


            if (!EventLog.Exists(logName, machineName))
            {
                ////Delete old log
                //if (EventLog.Exists(oldLogName, machineName))
                //{
                //    EventLog.Delete(oldLogName, machineName);
                //}

                

                //Create Source for the Log
                EventLog.CreateEventSource(source, logName, machineName);
                
                //Create Event
                EventLog eventLog = new EventLog(logName, machineName, source);
                eventLog.WriteEntry(eventName);
                try
                {
                    eventLog.WriteEntry(eventName, EventLogEntryType.Warning, 234, (short)3);
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    int x = 0;
                }
```

Comment: I think people can still understand your question. You should use more cryptic names then `S401` & `L401`

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @JimMischel Why the events are not created with log “Log402” when I uncomment the commented code? Though no errors in that case, the events are not getting added to the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is telling you *exactly* what the problem is. The event source named "Source401" already exists. You're deleting the old event log, "Log401", but you're not deleting the event source.

As [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7y6sy21.aspx) says:

> The operating system stores event logs as files. When you use EventLogInstaller or CreateEventSource to create a new event log, the associated file is stored in the %SystemRoot%\System32\Config directory on the specified computer. The file name is set by appending the first 8 characters of the Log property with the ".evt" file name extension.
>
> The source must be unique on the local computer; a new source name cannot match an existing source name or an existing event log name. Each source can write to only one event log at a time;

Also, this little nugget:

> If a source has already been mapped to a log and you remap it to a new log, you must restart the computer for the changes to take effect.

In addition, you might want to consider this, also from the documentation:

> Create the new event source during the installation of your application. This allows time for the operating system to refresh its list of registered event sources and their configuration. If the operating system has not refreshed its list of event sources, and you attempt to write an event with the new source, the write operation will fail

Finally, the `CreateEventSource` method you're calling is marked obsolete, and has been since .NET 2.0. There's usually a good reason for methods to be marked obsolete. You should be calling [CreateEventSource(EventSourceCreationData)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zbwd3s3.aspx).

I think you need to re-think the way you're using event logs. Your application shouldn't be creating and deleting logs that way. It's not how they're intended to be used.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer